# Change var value depending on which image is being swapped via jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jQuery function that swaps an image when it is clicked. This works well, However, I would also like to pass a parameter using $.get depending on which image is being displayed.

Here's the context.  I have a bunch of comments and a "thumbs up" image next to each. when the thumbs up is clicked, it turns green and calls a PHP script via the $.get method. this works, but I also want the user to be able to "un-thumbs up" so that if they click one that was already green, then can remove their up vote. Here is what I have so far.

**My jQuery:**

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {  

$('.thumb a').on('click', function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();
    var $img = $(this).find('img');

    var $idshow = $(this).attr("id");

    $img.attr('src', function(_,s) {
         return s.indexOf('thumbs_up_green') > -1 ? '../images/thumbs_up.png'
                                                  : '../images/thumbs_up_green.png'                                                                               
    });

    //HERE IS THE VARIABLE I WANT TO BE ABLE TO CHANGE
    var $action = "add";        

    $.get("thumb_up_tip.php?tip_id=" + $idshow + "&action=" + $action)      
});

});
</script>
```

In the above code, if the button is going from "thumbs_up.png" to "thumbs_up_green.png" I want the var $action to be "add". If it is going from "thumbs_up_green.png" to "thumbs_up.png" then I want the var $action to be "subtract".

Any recommendations would be great!

Answer (score 1):

When adding or unadding add a class to the element. Then on your click check to see what class exists and then decide your action based off of that.

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {  
    $('.thumb a').on('click', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var $img = $(this).find('img'),
          $idshow = $(this).attr("id"),
          $action = 'add';

      if($img.hasClass('thumbsUp')){
         $action = "remove";
         $img.removeClass('thumbsUp');
      }else{
        $img.addClass('thumbsUp');
      }

     $img.attr('src', function(_,s) { return s.indexOf('thumbs_up_green') > -1 ? '../images/thumbs_up.png' : '../images/thumbs_up_green.png'});
     $.get("thumb_up_tip.php?tip_id=" + $idshow + "&action=" + $action)      
   });
   });
</script>
```

Its going to check if a class exists on the element, if so this is already thumbs up so we should remove and vice versa.